# Where to find the YOLOv5 feature extractor?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, yolov5

I have to customize YOLOv5 feature extractor for a school project. I see a bunch of file after cloning the YOLOv5 git repository. But I don't know where is the feature extractor. Can someone guide me to some documents?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `_forward_once` in `BaseModel` to extract features. You can find it here:

https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/blob/868c0e9bbb45b031e7bfd73c6d3983bcce07b9c1/models/yolo.py#L114

Some relevant discussions:

- https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/385
- https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/1173